# Visual studio 2010 sp1 does not show Asp.net MVC applications

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I had VS 2010 sp1 that time it has MVC2 only,Now i was downloaded and installed MVC3. After the installation i have restarted my system and run the VS 2010, but it does not show any applications which is related to mvc2 and mvc3 or else.

how do i have Asp.net MVC applications in VS 2010 sp1?

IF anyone know, please share your idea....

Answer (score 2):

Once you [download and install ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=1491) ensure that you are creating a new ASP.NET application and not ASP.NET Website:

[image]

Comment: Hi Darin, i chose project only but it does not have any applications which is related to MVC applications. what do i do now?

Comment: Which version of VS2010 are you using?

Comment: Now i resolved the issue by reinstalling the MVC3 tools update. thanks for your reply